# CAS authentication - UrlRewriteFilter nullifies request.getRemoteUser() 

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, servlet-filters, cas

I'm trying to use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html) and here it is my urlrewrite.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.2//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.2.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/([a-z]+)$</from>
       <to>/$1.jsp</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

The problem is that `request.getRemoteUser()` is null if I'm accessing pages via forwarding.
When I'm accessing pages directly everything is OK.

I've checked out request headers and can not see any difference. 
I'm using CAS authentication and it looks like the problem is in exactly in CAS - 
I've tried to use http basic auth and everything is just fine.

So, the question is what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was pretty simple - since CAS wraps (I guess) request.getRemoteUser(), it is important to place UrlRewriteFilter **after** CAS Filters.

Hope this will help somebody else )